# Unable to create a package version for second generation managed package

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, salesforcedx-cli, package, 2gp

I'm trying to create a 2G managed package. The following were the steps I used

> sfdx force:package:create --name newManagedPackage --packagetype
> Managed --path force-app

I was able to create a package and the `sfdx-project.json` file was updated as below

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            "path": "force-app",
            "default": true,
            "package": "newManagedPackage",
            "versionName": "ver 0.1",
            "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT"
        }
    ],
    "name": "createmanagedpackage",
    "namespace": "devpackage11",
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "55.0",
    "packageAliases": {
        "newManagedPackage": "0Hoxxxxxxxx"
    } }
```

Next, I tried running the following command

> sfdx force:package:version:create --package newManagedPackage --wait 10 -x

I'm getting an error

```
**ERROR running force:package:version:create:  The provided package ID '0Hoxxxxxxxx' is invalid.**
```

When I tried to view the package details, I was able to see the managed package with the correct package ID. Not sure what's wrong here

Comment: Have you used `sfdx force:package:list` to double-check you have the correct package ID and that you are connected to the correct dev hub?